# Counting duplicate rows entries, RAM efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a BIG dataframe and want to get a count of how many there are of each rows.
I have been using this:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(), as_index=False, sort=False).size()
```

But it requires more than 60GB RAM, while I'm stuck with 32GB.

Then I came up with this, but it is painfully slow, it's been churning for 5+ hours on end:
The DF has 3 columns; two categorical and one string.

```
from collections import Counter

counts = df.groupby(['industry', 'sector'], as_index=False, sort=False).aggregate(Counter)

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for row in counts.iterrows():
    other = row[1][:-1].to_dict() 
    for job, n in row[1][-1].items():
        tmp_df = pd.DataFrame({
            **other,
            'job.jobTitlText': job,
            'size': n,
        }, index=[0])
        final_df = final_df.append(tmp_df) # append the tmp_df to our final df
final_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: What about `print(df.value_counts())` ?

Answer (score 2):

One of the columns is a categorial / enum column.

It turns out, that by default, Pandas will generate groups for categories even if they don't exist in the data.

The solution is to use `observed=True`, thus:

```
counts = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(), as_index=False, sort=False, observed=True).size()
```

Comment: Great find.... Should note in your question you have categorical data.